# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType' for Eye blinking detection

Tags: opencv, python-3.7

I am having a problem with "Eye blinking detection" using Python, OpenCV, and dlib. I am using Jupyter notebook.

The following code uses the `shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat` library which plot `68` predefine points on a face.

```py
 import cv2
 #import numpy as np
 import dlib
 from math import hypot

 cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

 detector = dlib.get_frontal_face_detector()
 predictor = dlib.shape_predictor("C:\\Users\\Asirajdin\\dev\\shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks
 \\shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat")


 def midpoint (p1, p2):
     return int ((p1.x + p2.x)/2), int ((p1.y + p2.y)/2)

 font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX

 def get_blinking_ratio (eye_points, facial_landmarks):
     left_point = (facial_landmarks.part(eye_points[0]).x, facial_landmarks.part(eye_points[0]).y)
     right_point = (facial_landmarks.part(eye_points[3]).x, facial_landmarks.part(eye_points[3]).y)
     centre_top = midpoint (facial_landmarks.part(eye_points[1]), facial_landmarks.part(eye_points[2]))
     centre_bottom = midpoint (facial_landmarks.part(eye_points[5]), 
     facial_landmarks.part(eye_points[4]))
    
 hor_line = cv2.line (frame, left_point, right_point, (0, 255,0), 2)
 ver_line = cv2.line (frame, centre_top, centre_bottom, (0, 255,0), 2)
    
 hor_line_length = hypot ((left_point[0] - right_point[0]), (left_point[1] - right_point[1])) 
 ver_line_length = hypot((centre_top[0] - centre_bottom[0]), (centre_top[1] - centre_bottom[1]))
    
 ratio = hor_line_length/ver_line_length
    

 while(True):

     _, frame = cap.read()
     gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    
     faces = detector(gray)
    
     for face in faces:
        #x, y = face.left(), face.top()
        #x1, y1 = face.right(), face.bottom()
        #cv2.rectangle(frame,(x, y), (x1, y1), (0, 255,0), 2)
        
        landmarks = predictor(gray, face)
        
        left_eye_ratio = get_blinking_ratio([36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41], landmarks)
        right_eye_ratio = get_blinking_ratio([42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47], landmarks)
        blinking_ratio = ((left_eye_ratio + right_eye_ratio) / 2)
        
        if blinking_ratio > 5.7:
            cv2.putText(frame, "BLINKING", (50, 150), font, 5, (255, 0, 0))
            
    
     cv2.imshow("Frame", frame)
     key = cv2.waitKey(1)
     if key == 27:
        break
     # when everything is done then release the capture        
     cap.release()
     cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-ca92d06b8ea8> in <module>
     45         left_eye_ratio = get_blinking_ratio([36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41], landmarks)
     46         right_eye_ratio = get_blinking_ratio([42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47], landmarks)
---> 47         blinking_ratio = ((left_eye_ratio + right_eye_ratio) / 2)
     48 
     49         if blinking_ratio > 5.7:

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'
```

Comment: I have suggested an edit. I tried to correct the indentation as best I could. If you still find a mistake then let me know.

Comment: Hm.. the predefined predictor that you are using seems to have `None` values in it

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution to my post. I realised that the hor_line_length and the ver_line_length returns NoneType, then I tried to convert the ratio to integer. I returned the ratio under get_blinking_ratio as int i.e

```
ratio = hor_line_length/ver_line_length
return int (ratio)
```

I am novice in python, though the code is working but this might not be the best answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

your function `get_blinking_ratio` does not return anything. in python that means it implicitly returns `None`.

that's how the None values show up in that division.

after your function there are some lines that seem to deal with ratios. did you intend for those to go inside the function? then you need to indent them. they still don't contain a `return` statement, which is needed for a function to return anything.